# Recieving uknown JSON to my API and parsing it

Tags: c#, json, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

I have API, that recieve JSON from body, which is send from some WebUI.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] MyModel request)
        {
            MyModel newRecord = new();

            try
            {
                newRecord.Id = null;
                newRecord.Date = request.Date;
                newRecord.Name = request.Name;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return StatusCode(400, $"Error: {e.Message}");
            }            

            return Ok(newRecord);
        }
}
```

But `request` is not constant. It changes with develepment.
Right know i have to match `MyModel` with `request` to work on JSON in Body. But it generates too much work, because of many changes.

Is there a solution, so I can recieve uknown JSON object and parse it inside of controler?

For example, is there a trick, so I can write

```
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] var request)
```

or something similiar?

Comment: You can use the dictionary as input then parse keys and values

Comment: Your model doesn't need to contain all the properties, just the ones you're interested in. What do you mean by "parse" then? If you don't know the names and types of properties involved, you're going to have to change your code anyway if the format of what they send you changes.

Comment: Let's say `Create([FromBody] var request)` was valid (it's not, but similar enough is possible), how would you work with it? If you don't know the properties, you can't use them at compile time. Who calls this endpoint? Cannot you just share the models in a NuGet (private?) package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Text.Json has an class called JsonElement which can be used to bind any JSON to it.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] JsonElement jsonElement)
{
    // Get a property
    var aJsonProperty = jsonElement.GetProperty("aJsonPropertyName").GetString();
    
    // Deserialize it to a specific type
    var specificType = jsonElement.Deserialize<SpecificType>();

    return NoContent();
}
```